# How to use Spring if you want to retrieve data from a web service that need an api key?

Tags: java, android, spring, android-annotations

I need to know how exactly you use the spring-android api to retrieve data from a web service that needs an api key.

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.rest.Get;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.rest.RequiresAuthentication;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.rest.Rest;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;

@Rest(rootUrl = "https://prod.api.pvp.net", converters = {MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface LeagueOfLegendsAPI {

    @Get("/api/lol/{region}/versions")
    String getVersion(Region region);
}
```

So as far as I understood, the request url would look like this:

> prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/{placeholder}/versions

But it should be:

> prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/{placeholder}/versions&api_key=xxx

How can I achieve this with androidannotations and the android spring framework?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same in Android, but in Java, if you just create another argument called api_key to the function getVersion, it will use "xxx": 'String getVersion(Region region, String api_key)'

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like?

```
@Get("/api/lol/{region}/versions?api_key={apiKey}")
String getVersion(Region region, String apiKey);
```

If you were using spring or something, with an @RequestParam you might have been able to get away without having to code the query params raw in the annotation value. But here I guess you'll have to do something like the above since I don't see any @PathVariable in your existing example